# Display a query with multiple post types and same relationship on a single page

Tags: php, custom-post-types

I am creating a client portal were my clients can maintain their projects and leave feedback in Wordpress. I have two custom post types called "Clients" and "Projects" and they each pull information from one another in the backend. When I create a client it automatically generates its postID to a drop down menu on the projects post type were I can assign a client to a project.

What I am trying to accomplish is by displaying all projects that are associated with the selected client on a single page on the front end. The single page will be the client portal, which is generated by the client post type.

**I can't seem to display the associated post with its postID. Here is my code for single.php which will be displaying the projects on the clients portal.**

```
   <?php 
     global $post; 
     $projects = new WP_Query( array( 
         'post_type'         => array( 'projects'), 
         'posts_per_page'    => -1,
         'post_status'     => 'publish',
'meta_query'        => array( 
    array( 
        'key'           => 'clientType', 
        'value'         => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',  
        'compare'       => 'LIKE', 
        'type'          => 'NUMERIC' 
 )))); 
  ?>
```

Below is the code I am using to assign a client to a projects in the admin panel of projects. This script displays any client that I created in the client page and display their names in a drop down menu.

```
 class projects {
  var $FOR_POST_TYPE = 'projects';
  var $SELECT_POST_TYPE = 'client_portal';
  var $SELECT_POST_LABEL = 'Client';
  var $box_id;
  var $box_label;
  var $field_id;
  var $field_label;
  var $field_name;
  var $meta_key;
  function __construct() {
  add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );
}
  function admin_init() {
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
  add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );
  $this->meta_key     = "_selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
  $this->box_id       = "select-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}-metabox";
  $this->field_id     = "selected-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
  $this->field_name   = "selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
  $this->box_label    = __( "Select {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'projects'         );
  $this->field_label  = __( "Choose {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'projects'    );
 }
  function add_meta_boxes() {
  add_meta_box(
   $this->box_id,
   $this->box_label,
   array( $this, 'select_box' ),
   $this->FOR_POST_TYPE,
   'side'
 );
 }
  function select_box( $post ) {
  $selected_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clientType', true );
  global $wp_post_types;
  $save_hierarchical = $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical;
  $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = true;
  wp_dropdown_pages( array(
 'id' => $this->field_id,
 'name' => $this->field_name,
 'selected' => empty( $selected_post_id ) ? 0 : $selected_post_id,
 'post_type' => $this->SELECT_POST_TYPE,
 'show_option_none' => $this->field_label,
      ));
  $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = $save_hierarchical;
      }
 function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == $this->FOR_POST_TYPE && isset( $_POST[$this->field_name] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'clientType', $_POST[$this->field_name] );
 }
 }
 }
  new projects();
```

Full code for single.php http://pastebin.com/na7djwsq

**Register Post Type I am using**

Project post type is called => **projects**

Clients post type is called => **client_portal**

Thank you

Comment: You should probably used `'paged' => $paged` instead of `$client_id` - Also, this is just a guess but shouldn't you use for your `meta_key` instead of `client` maybe `a_client` like you're saving in the metabox? What is it displaying now?

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions and they still come up blank. There seems to be an issue when I add the meta_query because when I remove the meta_query and just display the page_type I get all of the the projects displaying on the client page instead of the selected ones. When I place the meta_query back into the script the projects are not displaying. I can not figure out why the meta_query is not functioning correctly. @Howdy_McGee

Comment: :/ thats unfortunate. Are you 100% sure that `projects` is saving the correct client ID into a field called `client`? And are you 100% sure that `get_the_ID($client)` is pulling the correct ID and that it does correspond to the client ID saved in the project meta? Also it might be beneficial when you save your clientID meta (in the project CPT) that you convert it from an string to an integer.

Comment: No I am not 100% sure, more like 70%. The only thing I am 100% sure about is that the projects do display on the client page without the meta_query. But I have tried almost every scenario i can think of to display the projects. @Howdy_McGee

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50979/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-bigant841)